# Upload external image to webhost via php

Tags: php, image, upload, external

I want to upload an external image to my remote host via php.mean's that i wan't code which copy http://www.exaple.com/123.jpg to http://www.mysite.com/image.jpg.
Despite exec function ,due this function has been disabled by webhosting.
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:

`<?php exec("wget http://www.exaple.com/123.jpg"); exec("mv 123.jpg image.jpg")?>`

(this code is to be executed on the server www.mysite.com)

Comment: unfortunately exec function has been disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can run a php script to get the file and save it in your site.

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('http://www.exaple.com/123.jpg');
    if ($data !== false) {
        file_get_contents('image.jpg', $data);
    }
    else {
        // error in fetching the file
    }
```

`file_get_contents` is binary safe. you can find more about it from php website http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Comment: disable_functions show_source,allow_url_fopen what should i do?

Comment: another alternative is cURL